# Facebook - Show facebook user Feed in webview like browser

Tags: android, facebook, webview

Thank you in advance to see my Question.

I have task of facebook in my android application. I have to integrate  Facebook SDK for Authentication by facebook. When I use facebook api to get the feed of user that time i got the #JSON response from the server side. 
So I made the custom layout to show that user's feed.

But I need to show load the user feed in my webview in Android.
So Facebook provide any #Url for the user feed to load that Url webview? so we show facebook feed like #browser.

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/` is the address that shows a user’s news feed :-)

Comment: yes but how to manage user id or facebook access token for the particular user?

Comment: Not possible. They have to login inside the webview.

Answer (score 1):

Officially it is not possible to pass the Facebook SDK Token to a WebView. As far as I know it is currently not possible to do it.

One workaround I used in one of my apps (to display a like button before it was part of the SDK) is to set the Login Dialog to web only. By doing this the Facebook SDK creates a LoginDialog using a WebView whereby it has an active Facebook session after login.

This can be done by setting the [`LoginBehaviour`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginBehavior/) of either the [`LoginManager`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/) or the [`LoginButton`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginButton/):

```
login.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehaviour.WEB_ONLY);
```

Please be aware that this is only a workaround and could stop working in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just open `m.facebook.com` directly, this way it will take you to user's wall after login. and As its already logged in by authentication, session will remain active.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But i have use facebook graph Api for the login so i think browser havent authentication session token..